# build.gradle minsdk system when compile library

Tags: android

I have minSdkVersion 11 targetSdkVersion 19 , when I add compile some library and the library has minSdkVersion 14.
When I tried to run my project

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 11 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library com.me****:************

like this. But my code is working in layout-v14 it hasn't to be a problem what can I do for this ? Is there any setup different way minSdk or trick or something?

Comment: minSdkVersion is not mandatory so try remove from both AndroidManifest and check what happens.

Comment: but now it said Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 7 declared in library com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0